# How to rewrite url with subdomain in HAProxy

Tags: rewrite, haproxy

When user requests to http://sub1.example.com/a/b/c I need to replace this request's hostname header to example.com and rewrite the path to http://example.com/sub1/a/b/c.
I tried to use reqrep but I couldn't find how to add subdomain part into the path.

```
reqirep ^Host:\ (.*[^\.])(\.example\.com)      Host:\ example.com
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ (.*) \1\ /???/\2
```

I found %[req.hdr(host),lower,field(1,'.')] method to get subdomain name but I can't use it in reqrep method's replace part. How can I use variable in this part?

Comment: What version of HAProxy?  I'm guessing 1.6+... correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capture the subdomain into a request variable called `req.rewrite_example` (which is a name I just made up... the `req.` is required, the rest can be whatever you want)... do this by capturing the value of the `Host:` header, converting it to lowercase, then using the `regsub()` converter to scrub out the `.example.com` at the end.  Do this only if the hostname ends with `.example.com` -- otherwise the variable is undefined and the `-m found` tests in the subsequent rules will be false and those rules will not fire (which is what we want, for any other domain names we might see).

```
http-request set-var(req.rewrite_example) req.hdr(host),lower,regsub(\.example\.com$,) if { hdr_end(host) -i .example.com }
```

Insert the captured variable at the beginning of the path if the variable is defined (which it should be, if the first rule was a match).

```
http-request set-path /%[var(req.rewrite_example)]%[path] if { var(req.rewrite_example) -m found }
```

Replace the `Host:` header with the literal string `example.com` if the variable is defined.

```
http-request set-header Host example.com if { var(req.rewrite_example) -m found }
```

...send a request...

```
curl http://www.example.com/tacgnol.jpg
```

...and the following headers are being sent to the back-end:

```
GET /www/tacgnol.jpg HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Accept: */*
Host: example.com
```

Done.