# Change request without change url on browser HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I've configured `haproxy`, when i type `test.example.com` it redirects me to `example.com/test`

This is what I want, but the problem is that I want this happen without changing the url on the browser, I want it to keep `test.example.com` but send request to `example.com/test`

Here is my `haproxy.cfg`

```
frontend tt
     bind *:80
     bind *:443
     mode http
     default_backend ss
     bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.pem
     
     http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc } 

backend ss
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor 

http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] 
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } 
http-request set-var(req.rewrite_example) req.hdr(host),lower,regsub(\.example\.com$,) if { hdr_end(host) -i .example.com }
http-request set-path /%[var(req.rewrite_example)] if { var(req.rewrite_example) -m found }

http-request set-header Host example.com if { var(req.rewrite_example) -m found }
   option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1rnHost:localhost

server web1   example.com:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is almost working, please check the below few changes:

```
# ## example_fe ##
frontend example_fe
    bind *:80 
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.pem
    http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc } 
    mode http 
    default_backend example_be
# ## example_be ##
backend example_be
    mode http 
    balance roundrobin 
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] 
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } 
    http-request set-var(req.rewrite_example) req.hdr(host),lower,regsub(\.example\.com$,) if { hdr_end(host) -i .example.com } 
    http-request set-path /%[var(req.rewrite_example)]%[path] if { var(req.rewrite_example) -m found }
    http-request set-header Host example.com if { var(req.rewrite_example) -m found } 
    server web1 172.17.1.1:80
```

I have tested it on HAProxy version 2.4 and it works just fine.
The above config is driven from Michael: https://serverfault.com/a/815668/372988